# Is it possible to show the item icon in actionbar when action overflow clicked

Tags: android

I am using the action bar in my app, and I have two qustions:

1 As the image below, the items(item 1,item 2, item 3) is displayed without icon, is it possible to show the icon?

In fact the `icon` is set in the `menu.xml`.

[image]

2 Is it possible to know if the action bar is split-ed?

I use `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` to make the actionbar split-ed if necessary, but I want to know if it is split-ed in the runtime.